# Array of values (integers) and the prediction of the next value-to-be-added

Tags: ruby, arrays, prediction

I have this small problem and I'd like a pointer in the right direction.
Given is an array of values [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. I - as a human - need one fast look to understand the next value added is most likely 8.

How would you approach this problem with an algorithm? 
Do you know of a way to "guess" the next value?

I'm using ruby, but would be glad about any form of information.

Thank you,
Steviee

Answer (score 0):

Depend of arrays you want to predict value.

You can approach this problem with machines learning, but it's an heavy solution for the array you show us.

You can either find the equation if you know the "equation type" of the array:
In your case : (f(x) = ax+b

```
f(x) = x + 1;
```

where f(x) is the value and x the position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

One way to view this problem is as a [Curve Fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) question.

An example in ruby: http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2008/12/01/curve-fit-with-ruby-gsl.html